# How to add scripts through google sheets API v4 .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a script I need to run on every created spreadsheet. I tried SpreadsheetsResource.SheetsResource.CopyToRequest, in order to copy a template. However, it only copies the template without the script. If there is a work-around anyone can provide, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the Drive API, which copies all the data associated with the Drive item (vs the Sheets API which copies the Spreadsheet data)

Comment: Better yet, use an add-on

Comment: Thank you, I'll check out the Drive API. I don't think I can use an add-on since I'll be sending these forms to others to fill out.

Comment: Note that you must still authorize and create any form submit triggers in copied projects

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the Sheets API, use the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk), more specifically [File: Copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy).

To [create Apps Script projects programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects) we could use the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/)